# Cannot connect with SSH from iOS to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssh

I am using termius on my iPhone to try to reach by SSH my ubuntu 20.04, but always failing. I got the error: "Connection could not be established: Operation timed out"

I've tried with many other SSH apps but no results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*I cannot connect to my ssh server*" is a common new-user issue. Most commonly it means that either the new user misread the how-to-set-up-ssh instructions, or that the new user is perhaps a bit weak on their networking skills. We all had to learn sometime.

1. Simplify to make troubleshooting easier: Put your ssh client and ssh server on the same network. This is how you troubleshoot problems with account names, passwords, keys, and firewalls.

   Um, remember that your ssh server needs a consistent IP address. There are a couple ways to accomplish that. Double check that the server's IP address is still what you thought it was.
2. Once you have successful key-based ssh login on your client on the local network (LAN), then your Ubuntu server is configured correctly. Make no further changes.
3. If you can connect from the LAN, but not from the wider internet, then DON'T look to your Server.

   - Look at your router -- did you remember to set up *port forwarding*? If so, remember that you must use the *router's* IP address if connecting from the wider internet.
   - Is your router's firewall blocking your SSH port?
   - Some ISPs block port 22. Does yours? If they do, try a different port. (That means change your port-forwarding on your router, NOT your server).
4. The actual error message is important! An error of "invalid key" or "no such account" means to go back to step 1. An error of "cannot connect" means a network issue -- typically you are using the wrong IP address. Copy/paste the error message into your favorite Search Engine.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you receive means that your client is able to send an SSH connection request to your destination with all of your parameters correctly, yet the server does not respond to it.

Two main reasons for such error message:

1. Your remote machine has a firewall rule that does not allow you to connect to it. In most cases  it is a simple rule, and may be solved by creating a [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)  `allow` rule using `sudo ufw allow 22`.
   If you would like to close this TCP port again, use `sudo ufw deny 22`.
2. Your server in not accessible due to connectivity issues or wrong network configurations on your remote machine and / or private networks.

Comment: I have tried the (1) solution but still got the same error.
For the 2nd, I changed for another network but still not working. 
Do we need a config file in the .ssh folder?

Comment: Then this is might be a network related issue. As user535733 stated in their answer, there are some basic network troubleshooting that needs to be done - try them so you'll have some clue about what is causing the issue. You could also edit your question and add your findings so we can help you better.

Comment: It was my router which was not configured :( Thx all!